# Julia: Is there a way to return an iterator of each value of an index?

Tags: julia

Consider `m = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`

```
for idx in eachindex(m)
  println(idx)
end
```

I was expecting it to print `(1, 1) (2, 1), (3, 1) .... (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)` but it prints `1, 2, ..., 9`.

What's the most elegant way to loop through all the indices of a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
julia> for i in CartesianIndices(m)
           println(Tuple(i))
       end
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(3, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(3, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(3, 3)
```

(You can access the tuple of *sub*indices of `i::CartseianIndex` with `Tuple(i)`.)

Comment: To be exact, what `eachindex` returns depends on the thing you call it, and what is most efficient for it. For `Array`, this is `LinearIndices` by default. For views, it is `CartesianIndices`.

Comment: I think it's probably better to write `Tuple(i)` rather than `i.I`, since accessing fields relies on internal implementation details of the type. If the implementation changes, it could stop working.

Comment: Ha I knew it! I tried `tuple(i)` first (the function with non-capital `T` instead of the type) which did not work. Thanks for letting us know. I edited the answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily elegant but it works:

```
for i in eachindex(view(m, 1:size(m)[1], 1:size(m)[2]))
       println(i)
end

CartesianIndex(1, 1)
CartesianIndex(2, 1)
CartesianIndex(3, 1)
CartesianIndex(1, 2)
CartesianIndex(2, 2)
CartesianIndex(3, 2)
CartesianIndex(1, 3)
CartesianIndex(2, 3)
CartesianIndex(3, 3)
```

The reason is that an `Array` uses fast linear indices (a range `1:length(m)`), but not all arrays do, and in particular `view`s don't. Those arrays use Cartesian indices.

Comment: why dont i just do this? `for (i, j) in zip(OneTo.(size(m))...)`

Comment: I thought you wanted `i` to be actual indices into `m`.